# jQuery mobile: Dealing with large filtered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I have a jQuery mobile an alphabetically ordered, divided list as follows:

```
        <ul id="theList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search ticker or firm name..." data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
                <li data-filtertext="itemName"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                 .
                 .
                <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
                <li data-filtertext="itemName"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                 .
                 .
        </ul>
```

On page load I populate the list with 1000 items that were generated at random and put into an sqlite database.  Generating and displaying the list initially is smooth.  The issue is since this is a filtered list I would like users to be able to search it.  Searching is quite slow with this many items.

What is a good strategy to dealing with this??  Perhaps I could query the data on demand?  Heres what I have to work with:

- An SQLITE database that I can query
- A list of some sort.  I would like the list to stay in ABC order.
- The list has dividers.

I would like this to scale to N many items so that the list can be very big but still runs smoothly.  I am unsure how large the list could grow.

Answer (score 0):

Your search should not run that slowly for 1000 items. A good match/no match algorithm can run in less than `O(N)`, and as you're keeping the sort order constant, you're not adding the `N!` from quicksort. Can I see your jQuery filter-specific code? I'll advise on performance when it comes in.

As for the actual way you want to do this, if you do not initially want to load 1000 requests, consider loading and paginating using AJAX.

Comment: It's the default jQuery mobile filtered list.  There is no javascript I apply, only reference the jQuery mobile.js and it automatically creates the search filter.  I agree it should not be that slow but I assume that a lot of DOM manipulation is very intense.  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-search.html

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a phonegap app and found the jquerymobile listview filter incredibly slow - I had to wait 2-3 seconds before each key press was accepted into the search box; it was worse for iOS than for Android.

In the end I gave up and am now using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net) instead of listview   - it is a lot faster and has many more features.